# Splunk simulate show source button

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, splunk

I'm trying to write a script which gets a payload from my splunk enterprise account. I'm using BeautifulSoup for this (splunk-sdk not working for me, maybe due to not having admin access). I'm following the code from here (http://www.emalis.com/2018/11/python-script-that-uses-splunk-web-log-to-authenticate-then-searches-splunk-logs-non-admin-user-using-requests/).

I tried various search terms, one of those worked for me: `post_search_body = {'search': "search <request> request received earliest=-30hours"}`. However, I want to go into one of these results' show source button, and get all the results from there, and select some result from there.
Endpoint looks something like this:

```
https://splunk.splunkcompany.com/en-US/app/search/show_source?sid=<sid>&offset=1&lates
```

Can anyone suggest how do we go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like most (if not all) of the Splunk UI, it's backed by a REST command.  There's a good description of the Show Source feature written by a former Splunker at https://community.splunk.com/t5/Archive/no-of-events-in-show-source-view/td-p/94355